# Android Wear Support Jar

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm in the Android Wear preview but my computer crashed and I lost the wearable-preview-support.jar.  I also can't find my confirmation in my email.  Does anyone know if there is a console somewhere that I can redownload it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the archive here: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B39_TcfZ2v6NajZ3Q3UwdU5SQVk

You might be required to sign in with your Google-Account used to sign-up for the Google Wear Developer Preview.